# Remove an activity from stack in android

Tags: java, android, android-activity, activity-stack

I want to remove an activity from stack using code.Heres my case

> 1. From page A I am going to page B.
> 2. From page B i have to return to page A using return button.
> 3. In page B I am having a button which takes to page C.
> 4. When I click that button in page B , I am calling

```
finish(); //to remove PageB from stack
```

Ok, Here is the issue, From Page C when I click the return button I am taken to page A. because it is in stack.

> I want to remove Page A from stack when I click the button in page B.

Please note that I cant call a finish() in page A when calling Page B because I want to return back to page A. Only case I dont want to return is when the button in page B is clicked.

How can I do this in android?
Thanks

Comment: so if you are in C on which activity you want to go when back is pressed?

Comment: Actually process started from C,Then to A, then B ,In B I am clicking logout So it comes back to C which is login screen. So from this I dont want to go back to any screen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than calling `startActivity` in A when you start B, call [`startActivityForResult`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29).  Then in, your activity for A, handle [`onActivityResult`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult%28int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent%29).

Now, in B, when you open C, call [`setResult`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setResult%28int%29) before calling finish.  This will allow you to set some data to get passed back to A's `onActivityResult` method.  Pass a flag to indicate that A should close itself and then call `finish`.  Handle that flag in A's `onActivityResult`.

This way, each activity is responsible for closing itself and you're not artificially messing with the back stack.  Using intent flags work fine in a simple A,B,C case, but will probably fall apart if these 3 screens are part of a larger solution (i.e. A,B and C are deep under a stack of activities you don't want to mess with).

Answer (score 4):

Instead of finishing the current Activity you can jump directly to another Activity by starting an Intent.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyTarget.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use startActivity() to call A again from B.

Answer (score 0):

Surely there is a better answer [on this page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/tasks-and-back-stack.html) but, as a workaround, you could use SharedPreferences to pass a message to Activity A, requesting that it also finishes.

**Activity A:**

```
public class A extends Activity {

  public static final String CLOSE_A_ON_RESUME = "CLOSE_A_ON_RESUME";

  @Override
  public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();

    //Retrieve the message
    SharedPreferences mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    boolean IShouldClose=mPrefs.getBoolean(A.CLOSE_A_ON_RESUME,false);

    if (IShouldClose){

       //remove the message (will always close here otherwise)
       mPrefs.edit().remove(A.CLOSE_A_ON_RESUME).commit();

       //Terminate A
       finish();
    }
}
```

**Activity C:**

```
public class C extends Activity {

  /*
   * Stores an application wide private message to request that A closes on resume
   * call this in your button click handler
   */
  private void finishCthenA(){

    //Store the message
    SharedPreferences mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    mPrefs.edit().putBoolean(A.CLOSE_A_ON_RESUME,true).commit();

    //finish C
    finish();
}
```

Note that this is somewhat risky since the preferences survive the reboots and it can prevent A to start if, for example, your application is killed before A resumes.
To work around this, you should also remove the message in A.onCreate()